Why the extracted audio from Kinesis Video Stream is so noisy - AWS Lambda Python
In my Amazon Connect Flow, I've used "Start Media Streaming" block to stream audio to Kinesis video stream. When I get data from video stream using GET_MEDIA API, there is a lot of noise and distortion in the audio that I cannot recognize the words spoken in the audio.
Your effort/advice to fix the issue in below AWS Lambda function will be highly appreciated.
import boto3
import json
import wave
import io

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Lambda function started")
    
    # Extract StreamARN and FragmentStartNumber from the event
    # Currently hard coded
    stream_arn = 'arn:aws:kinesisvideo:ap-southeast-1:xxxxx:stream/audio-connect-e97b519c-b689-4dcf-a6e0-xxxxx/xxxxx'
    fragment_start_number = '91343852333xxxxx661842844xxxxx628'

    print(f"StreamARN: {stream_arn}")
    print(f"FragmentStartNumber: {fragment_start_number}")

    # Initialize the Kinesis Video client
    kinesis_video_client = boto3.client('kinesisvideo')
    print("Kinesis Video client initialized")

    # Get the endpoint from GetDataEndpoint API
    endpoint = kinesis_video_client.get_data_endpoint(StreamARN=stream_arn, APIName='GET_MEDIA')['DataEndpoint']
    print(f"Data endpoint: {endpoint}")

    # Create a Kinesis Video Media client with the endpoint URL
    kinesis_video_media_client = boto3.client('kinesis-video-media', endpoint_url=endpoint)
    print("Kinesis Video Media client created with endpoint URL")

    # Use the 'get_media' API to retrieve the video stream
    media_response = kinesis_video_media_client.get_media(StreamARN=stream_arn,StartSelector={
        'StartSelectorType': 'FRAGMENT_NUMBER',
        'AfterFragmentNumber': fragment_start_number
    })
    print("Video stream retrieved using 'get_media' API")

    # The video stream is available in the 'Payload' key of the media_response
    video_stream = media_response['Payload']
    print("Video stream extracted from media response")

    # Decode raw audio data
    audio_data = video_stream.read()

    # Encode audio data into WAV format
    with io.BytesIO(audio_data) as audio_buffer:
        with wave.open(audio_buffer, 'wb') as wav_file:
            wav_file.setnchannels(1)  # Mono
            wav_file.setsampwidth(2)  # 2 bytes per sample
            wav_file.setframerate(8000)  # Sample rate
            wav_file.writeframes(audio_data)
    
        # Specify S3 bucket and object key name
        s3_bucket = 'amazon-connect-xxxxx'
        s3_key = f'voicemails/{fragment_start_number}.wav'
        print(f"S3 Bucket: {s3_bucket}")
        print(f"S3 Key: {s3_key}")
        
        # Initialize the S3 client
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
        print("S3 client initialized")
        
        # Upload the WAV file to the S3 bucket
        audio_buffer.seek(0)  # Reset buffer position to start
        s3_client.upload_fileobj(audio_buffer, s3_bucket, s3_key)
        print("WAV file uploaded to S3 bucket")
    
    print("Lambda function completed successfully")
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps("Audio extraction and upload completed successfully")
    }

